# post data with ajax without reloading

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to upload a file and get the post data in my page.

With usual form it works fine:

```
<form id="formulario" action="nextPage" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <input type="file" name="aux.urlFile" id="InputDocumento" value =""></input>

</form>
```

In "nextPage" I can see the post value is

```
aux.urlFile UPLOADEDFILES*fileDefault#0d08abdfdfcc90f6461fff25236e_aux_urlFile_data_cdata2_psf_B46A0E4F94194001404ED107*data_cdata2.psf*application/octet-stream
```

Now, I want to do it without reload the page:

```
 <form id="formulario" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <input type="file" name="aux.urlFile" id="InputDocumento" value ="">
 </input>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).on('submit','#formulario',function(){

event.preventDefault();
var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);


for (var [key, value] of formData.entries()) { 
  console.log(key, value);
}


$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  data: formData,
  processData : false,
  success:function (data) {
     debugger;
  },
  error: function (jXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert(errorThrown);
  }
});
```

});

In console:

```
aux.urlFile 
FilelastModified: 1482486542000
lastModifiedDate: Fri Dec 23 2016 10:49:02 GMT+0100 (Romance Standard Time)
name: "1.psf"
 size: 1675type: "
"webkitRelativePath: "
"__proto__: File
```

And in success only the html code in my page. How can I get the post value and check if the file is uploaded?

Comment: `$(this)[0]` is the same thing as `this`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Ajax File Upload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload)

Comment: `function()` should be `function(event)`. Using `event` as a global variable doesn't work in most browsers.